# How to use set environment variables as argument for command line scripts through python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-os

I'm writing a script to convert files from one format to other, say from t1 to t2. The conversion uses a shell script, to call this I need to set few variables and later pass the files(t1) as arguments. To set environment variables I'm using os.environ function, I need to use a file from previously set variable's path. I have tried explaining the situation below :

```
os.environ['var1'] = 'path/to/var1'
os.environ['var2'] = '$var1/path/to/var2'
os.environ['svar'] = 'path/for/files.t1/source'
$var2/script.sh $svar/file.t1 -conv file.t2
```

Consider a Path P, the first half of it can be changed and second half remains constant. from the above code path to var1 changes based on requirement and path to var2 is constant. The combined path has a script file that is invoked for converting the file. 
I need help with the 3rd line above, I'm not sure how to call a file in defined variables(var1,var2) path along with other arguments. I used subprocess.check_call (), but unable to get right syntax.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Generally, we'd like to see full code that we can copy/paste and run ourselves.  Can you please post a minimal runnable example.  This will allow us to see how you are using the subprocess module.  What you've posted almost looks like some kind of a command-line utility, but I assume from the tags you are actually using Python?

Comment: yes, I'm using python. I will edit the question

Comment: As an aside, why use environment variables here?

Comment: Please try to clarify further.

This looks almost as if you try to translate a bash script to python.
If this is the case, then post the smallest possible working bash script and we can help converting it to python.

It might also be a good idea to read a basic python tutorial.

Also please  always try to post the smallest possible example allowing us to reproduce your proble, tell us what you'd like to achieve and how your current attemplt fails.

Comment: I have updated the question,  please check. @FrankMerrow

Comment: @gelonida please check

Comment: @AMC please Check

Comment: I know it's not directly related to the issue, but I still don't feel that using environments variables here is necessary or worthwhile.

Comment: _I'm not sure how to call a file in defined variables(var1,var2) path along with other arguments._ What do you mean by _call a file_ ?

Comment: tried to claryfy my answer further.

Could you please comment, whether my answer helped or post your own answer, so that others can benefit from this question?

Answer (score 0):

Even with the new description I'm a little lost, why you want to pass paths as environment variables AND as command line arguments.

Normally one of both should suffice (depending on how the script to be called has been implemented)

but if I interpret your question correctly, this is what you try to do.
But perhaps you give exactly one example of a  shell session (from a new shell) to show how you call the script manually.

I'm using now also `os.path.join()` instead of `+`, which is the recommended way for joining paths (thanks @Frank Merrow, initially I thought this will make the code less easy to follow)

Please show any errors and describe any problem, that you encounter with below code.

```
import os
import subprocess
var1 = os.environ['var1'] = 'path/to/var1'
var2 = os.environ['var2'] = os.path.join(var1, 'path/to/var2')
svar = os.environ['svar'] = 'path/for/files.t1/source'
cmd = [ 
    os.path.join(var2, "script.sh"), 
    os.path.join(svar, "file.t1"),
    "-conv",
    "file.t2",
    ]
print("command will be %s" % cmd)  # this line just for debugging
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Below a small example of a shell script to see what it would get:

**script.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "I got called with following parameters $*"
echo "\$1 is <$1>" # should be path/for/files.t1/source/file.t1
echo "\$2 is <$2>" # should be -conv
echo "\$4 is <$3>" # should be file.t2
echo "The environment variable 'var1' is <$var1>" # should be path/to/var1
echo "The environment variable 'var2' is <$var2>" # should be path/to/var1/path/to/var2
echo "The environment variable 'svar' is <$svar>" # should be path/for/files.t1/source
var1 = os.environ['var1'] = 'path/to/var1'
var2 = os.environ['var2'] = os.path.join(var1, 'path/to/var2')
svar = os.environ['svar'] = 'path/for/files.t1/source
```

Comment: As a minor nit, I would use os.path.join() instead of string append for portability.

Comment: Small question @gelonida, I tried the method u told, here I'm using os.environ('var1') method to set var1. But in path.join() I'm  using var1 (not in quotes). Will the script recognize the env variable

Comment: if  you write `a = b = <expression>`, then the result of the expression is assigned to `b` and to `a`.
In my code I assigned the value to `os.environ['var1']` and also to `var1` this is just to have less typing to do in the lines that follow.

so either use `os.environ["var1"]` or if you use it multiple times and you don't want to type that much assign it explicitly (like in my example) to a python variable `var1`